# Hibernate, Java, inserting 3 decimal points

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm creating a simple struts 2 web app utilizing Hibernate. I'd like the user to be a able to enter 3 items.

Environment: eg "Windows"
Version: eg 10.2.0
Notes: eg "Windows is the beez kneez"

However I'm not sure what primitive data type I would use for Version as it has 2 decimals when creating my Java Object? Is it a Float? is it a Double? How would I approach it if it was something like 10.2.3.5?

Answer (score 0):

Decimal values contain a single decimal. If you want multiple decimals, you'll need a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.text.DecimalFormat
```

Using this class would be a better approach

This link might [help](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html)